# Keras training batch containing biased input

Tags: keras

Is there any side effect if a specific Keras training batch contains biased input (all positive or all negative)? However, over the entire epoch, the training data is somewhat balanced.

Comment: From a statistical point of view I think the process of stochastic gradient descent makes it work. You will do steps in each directions that should balance each other. But , it should be more performant (faster to optimize) if your batches are more representative of your overall data. The stochastic steps (gradients) will be probably better oriented.